# Laravel 5.5 How to add dynamic conditions inside a relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a relation to get the friends created on specific date which is working with a static date parameter

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class)->where('created_at','2018-01-31');
}
```

But i need to get it for a dynamic date where the $request variable is unavailable inside a relation. I tried like this which is not working

```
public function friends($request)
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class)->where('created_at',$request->date);
}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel helper function [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request)

> The ***request*** function returns the current request instance or obtains an input item

```
public function friends()
{
    $date = request('date') ? : '2018-01-31'; // You can choose a default date, here '2018-01-31'

    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class)->where('created_at', $date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Model will remain same as you posted:

```
public function friends($date)
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class)->where('created_at', $date);
}
```

In your controller(example):

```
$fooFriends = $foo->friends('2018-01-30')->get();

//Directly from $request or you can use different values/vars each time
$fooFriends = $foo->friends($request->date)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in controller

```
public function data(){

    Mdalname::friend($value)
}
```

And in modal

```
public function friends($value )
{

    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class)->where('created_at', $value);
}
```