# How to join two table in mysql with array condition

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, left-join

I want to join two tables where the conditions of each table are stored in array-

How to join this using array in where condition

Condition 1:

```
$date = [
         'month' => $month,
         'year' => $year
        ];
```

Condition 2:

```
$request=[
            'id' => $as_id,
            'unit' => $unit_id
         ]
```

```
DB::table('hr_monthly_salary AS s')
    ->where($date)
    ->leftJoin('hr_as_basic_info as e', 'e.associate_id', '=', 's.as_id')
```

`$date` is condition for `hr_monthly_salary` and `$request` is condition for `hr_as_basic_info`

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not pretty sure about this solution, but you can try this out.

> Query

```
$users = DB::table('hr_monthly_salary AS s')->with('hr_as_basic_info')->where([
                ['month', '=', $month],
                ['year', '=', $year],
            ])->get();
```

> Model Relationship

```
public function hr_as_basic_info() {
            return $this->belongsTo('YOUR_MODEL')->where([
                ['id', '=', $as_id],
                ['year', '=', $unit_id]
            ]);
        }
```

To use your dynamic values inside relationship you can refer to this

[Laravel 5.5 How to add dynamic conditions inside a relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543763/laravel-5-5-how-to-add-dynamic-conditions-inside-a-relationship)